# Aggregate using external references in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'd like to aggregate results in a mongodb query, however I am not able to accomplish that in the case modeled like the following example from mongodb.org:

```
{
   _id: "oreilly",
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA"
}

{
   _id: 123456789,
   title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
   author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
   published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
   pages: 216,
   language: "English",
   publisher_id: "oreilly"
}

{
   _id: 234567890,
   title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
   author: "Kristina Chodorow",
   published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
   pages: 68,
   language: "English",
   publisher_id: "oreilly"
}
```

My result should have this structure:

```
{
    publishers: [
    {
        _id: "oreilly",
        name: "O'Reilly Media",
        founded: 1980,
        location: "CA"
        books: [
            {
                 _id: 123456789,
                 title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
                 author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
                 published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
                 pages: 216,
                 language: "English"
            },
            {
                 _id: 234567890,
                 title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
                 author: "Kristina Chodorow",
                 published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
                 pages: 68,
                 language: "English",
                 publisher_id: "oreilly"
             }
        ]
        }        
    ]
}
```

But I cannot manage to use the $aggregate query on the books table to populate the publisher reference, and I don't even know if it is possible.

What are the proper strategies to get this kind of result?

Comment: The publisher document with `name`, `founded`, and `location` is in a different collection from the book documents? MongoDB doesn't do joins. You won't be able to produce your output document with one operation if the publisher document is in a different collection.

Comment: I see, what do you'd suggest then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the result is to simulate the join by iterate each publisher to find his books and then construct your result :)

sample in mongo shell:

```
var publishers = []; 
var struct = {};
struct.publishers = publishers
db.publisher.find().forEach( function(publisher) {        
        publisher.books = db.books.find({publisher_id: publisher._id}).toArray()
        publishers.push(publisher)
})
printjson(struct)
```

sample for drivers:

You can use [db.eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/#db.eval) to run a query as [Server-side Javascript](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/).

db.eval:
`connection.db.eval(function construct(publisher){return struct}), arg ,function (e, result) {result});`

db.eval function:

```
db.eval(function construct(publisher) {
    var publishers = []; 
    var struct = {};
    var query = publisher ? {_id:publisher} : {}
    struct.publishers = publishers
    db.publisher.find(query).forEach( function(publisher) {
        publisher.books = db.books.find({publisher_id: publisher._id}).toArray()
        publishers.push(publisher)
    })
return struct
}
,null // argument to pass into function for filter, e.g. 'oreilly'
,{nolock:true})
```

sample with mongoose: (on collection name book)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/book');
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
  mongoose.connection.db.eval(function construct(publisher) {
      var publishers = [];
      var struct = {};
      var query = publisher ? {_id:publisher} : {}
      struct.publishers = publishers
      db.publisher.find(query).forEach( function(publisher) {
          publisher.books = db.books.find({publisher_id: publisher._id}).toArray()
          publishers.push(publisher)
      })
  return struct
  }
  ,'oreilly'
  ,{nolock:true}, function(e,result) {
    if(e) console.log(e);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  })
})
```

Comment: nice solution. As far as you know, is it possible to bring this logic and its synchronous fashion into Mongoose?

Comment: Yes it is, you can use [eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) or [db.eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/), its give you ability to run Javascript at MongoDB Server. [mongoose connection](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) always passed the connection db instance, then you can use the **db** to run db.runCommand({eval: function([...}), args:[]}) or db.eval. Let me add some sample in the answer

Comment: I've tried your second example of eval(). Are you sure that the function which is passed as first parameter isn't to be sent in string format?

Comment: trying the first example case I get this error: `TypeError: Object #<Db> has no method 'runCommand'`

Comment: The db.eval() taking first parameter as a javascript code not a string :), please see [db.js](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/lib/db.js#L489). My bad the 'runCommand' is not support in current driver, I'll remove it from the answer. –  tug 33 mins ago